# Xamarin.forms Acr userdialog loading indicator not showing

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a xamarin forms app.In my app I have button click which will call certain Web api and show popups(Rg.popUp plugin) according to my logic. The problem Iam facing is I am trying to implemet Acr.Userdialog activity indicator when the user clicks the button. What is my intention is when user clicks the button, the indicator should show up and API calls to be done in background till the popups shows.

**What I have done**

```
namespace sampleapp
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        string truequescount;
        MobileListData mobileListData = new MobileListData();
        StateListData stateListData = new StateListData();
        UserMappedStateListData userMappedStateListData = new UserMappedStateListData();
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();               
            LoadScreenItems();          
        }

        private async void submit_clicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {                 
            if (StateListData.Entry[0].State.Contains(State_picker.Text))
            {
                UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading("submitting data...");               
                try
                {                      
                    //My API Calls                         
                    if (transactions[0].Questions.Count < 5)
                    {   
                        // navigation 1 according to condition  
                        UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();                    
                        await PopupNavigation.PushAsync(new NoDataPopUp());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //some logic                        
                        if (ObjQuestionData.Count < 1)
                        {    
                            //navigation 2 according to condition
                            UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();                      
                            await PopupNavigation.PushAsync(new InsuffQdata());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //some logic
                        }                      
                    }
                    // Orginal navigation if all conditions surpassed
                    UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
                    await Navigation.PushAsync(new SecurityQuestionScreen(tranzaction, formdata));                        
                } 
                catch (Exception) 
                {                   
                }        
            }
            else
            {
                // another navigation according to condition
                UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
                await PopupNavigation.PushAsync(new FormVerificationPopup(formdata));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

According to my code loading indicator only shows after popup appears.Any help appreciated.

**Edit**

I tried to load this in Main thread and it worked fine. But now it is only working in android 9.0. It is not showing on any devices under android 9. What will be the reason?

Comment: Did you try to run on MainThread or UIThread ?

Comment: Just debug the source code and see if the expression "StateListData.Entry[0].State.Contains(State_picker.Text)" returns true.

Comment: @yanng you...Yes bro api and everything works fine...I just cant show that indicator..If I run it on main thread, will it work?

Comment: Can you put await Task.Delay(200) above show loading and try again

Comment: @AditKothari bro it worked when i run it on main thread...I updated my question..can you help me?

Comment: how about change the method signature from "private async void submit_clicked(...)" to " private async Task submit_clicked(...)". I got the idea from https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/76524/userdialogs-instance-showloading-message-dissapears

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => {

                try
                {
                using (this.Dialogs.Loading("Loading..."))
                {
                        await Task.Delay(300);
                        //Your Service code
                }
              }
  catch (Exception ex)
        {
                var val=ex.Message;
            UserDialogs.Instance.Alert("Test", val.ToString(), "Ok");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Bro will it solve the issue of not showing in android 8.0 and below?

Comment: worked for me once... you check and let me know .. did it helped you or not.

Comment: is there any diffrence between UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading("submitting data...");  and using (this.Dialogs.Loading("Loading..."))

Comment: No difference .. i am just calling this.Dialogs.Loading("Loading...") from base class.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this
await Task.Delay(200);
UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading("submitting data...");

Comment: Ok let me check bro

Comment: Adding await Task.Delay(200) works for my case also. Can you please explain how it is working and is it advised to use Task.Delay ?